# How do I sum for all of true/false of each WITH SELECT to the final result in Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have my query like this

```
with group1 as (
  select 
    (
      contains(array1, 'element_1')
    ) AS matches, 
    count(*) 
  from 
    // from statement 
  where 
    // where statement 
  group by 
    1
), 
group2 as (
  select 
    (
      contains(array1, 'element_2')
    ) AS matches, 
    count(*) 
  from 
    // from statement1 
  where 
    // where statement1 
  group by 
    1
) 
select 
  * 
from 
  group1, 
  group2
```

The result of group1 or group2 would look something like this

```
group1
true, 10
false, 20
```

```
group2
true, 30
false, 40
```

I want the final result to be
true, 40
false, 60

The reason that I have to use `WITH` statement is because the two queries can have different where statements as well as the check to the `matches`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `union` the 2 groups together, and then do another group by and sum the counts

```
with group1 as (
  select 
    (
      contains(array1, 'element_1')
    ) AS matches, 
    count(*) as amount
  from 
    // from statement 
  where 
    // where statement 
  group by 
    1
), 
group2 as (
  select 
    (
      contains(array1, 'element_2')
    ) AS matches, 
    count(*) as amount
  from 
    // from statement1 
  where 
    // where statement1 
  group by 
    1
) 
select matches, sum(amount) as amount 
from 
(select * from group1
union all
select * from group2)
group by 1
```